# Visual studio crash loses all newly set breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, crash, breakpoints, data-loss

Whenever my installation of Visual Studio 2010 Professional crashes while running my VC++ application, I lose all breakpoints that I set during that session (other breakpoints from previous sessions remain), leading me to believe that breakpoints are only truly saved on project closing. Can anyone confirm this, and offer a useful tip (other than occasionally closing and reopening my project)?

Note: By session I don't mean debugging session but just the time period in which the project is open.

Comment: This is pretty standard in any program.  Because the alternative is much much worse.  Persisting settings early severely increases the odds that restarting the program will cause an immediate crash again.  You only ever save them when you're sure that the settings don't cause problems.  Clearly the real problem here is VS crashing.  That's not normal, you'll need to get that fixed.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Too bad I can't mark a comment as an answer ;)

Comment: imo it should save the breakpoints when you save all files instead of saving them when you close the project. But it appears thats not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you change your breakpoints very often? It is possible to Export breakpoints for later re-use:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/21/vs-2010-debugger-improvements-breakpoints-datatips-import-export.aspx